# Google adwords conversion tracking on jquery mobile subpage

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-ads-api

I have a subpage in a jquery mobile page where I'd like to insert att Google adwords conversion cookie. But using the traditional snippet from Adwords doesn't work. On Android it even makes the page go blank.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you want to share more information? :) E.g. what is a jQuery subpage and what is the code you tried already (which made the page blank)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably loading the conversion script later on the page by doing something like this:

```js
(function(){
    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var ga=document.createElement('script');
    ga.type='text/javascript';
    ga.async=true;
    ga.src='http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);
})();
```

Or using a jQuery function to load scripts that is similar to the function above. Turns out that you can't include the `conversion.js` script in this manner because it uses `document.write` to write the img tag on the page. Because it uses `document.write` some browsers will remove everything from the page and replace the content with the output of `document.write`, which in this case is an empty gif.

You better use the default tag provided by google to mark a conversion. If you need to load it without a page refresh just open an iframe to a page that contains this tracking code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
  var google_conversion_language = "en_US";
  var google_conversion_format = "1";
  var google_conversion_color = "666666";
  var google_conversion_label = "Purchase";
  if (10.0) {
    var google_conversion_value = 10.0
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height=1 width=1 border=0 
  src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567890/?value=10.0&label=Purchase&script=0">
</noscript>
```

Of course this is just an example. You should use your own code that have your unique conversiod_id.

Comment: +1 for the insight that conversion.js uses document.write to output the result.

Comment: For an alternative to using an iframe - overwriting the document.write() method: http://articles.adamwrobel.com/2010/12/23/trigger-adwords-conversion-on-javascript-event

Answer (score 2):

I researched this a bit, and came across the following links:

- http://www.google.com/ads/mobile/publishers/web-publishers.html
- https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185668

So it looks like depending on the type of ad you're running, you will have to get a customized unit for mobile.

However, I am still not sure why the page would go blank. I mean, I can totally see how some *ad code* does that when you try to lazy-load it, but I'm not sure why it happens in your situation.